# Overloading operator +. String class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

Im writing string class by myself. And I overloaded + operator. Its works fine, but then I tried to eguate `cstr = str +pop`  , its did nothing. `You could see my error in  main() function. Complier doesnt give any mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class S {

public:
          S();
          S(const char *str);
          S(const S &s);

         ~S() { delete []string;}
          S  &operator  =(const S   &s);

          int  lenght() const {return l     ;}
      char*  strS() const {return string;}

      friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &, const S &first) {cout<<first.string;}
      friend S    operator+ (const S& first, const S& second);

private:
          char *string;
          int l;

};

int main(){
S pop("Q6");
S str("M5");

S cstr = str +pop; // works correct
cout<<str;

str = str + pop;
cout<<str ;        // doesnt work, it doesnt write in terminal

return 0;
}
S::S()
{
    l = 0;
    string = new char[1];
    string[0]='\0';
}

S::S(const char *str)
{
    l      = strlen(str);
    string = new   char[l+1];
    memcpy(string, str, l+1);
}

S::S(const S &s)
{
     l = s.l;
     string = new char[l+1];
     memcpy(string,s.string,l+1);
}

S &S::operator=(const S &s)
{
    if (this != &s)
    {
        delete []string;
        string = new char[s.l+1];
        memcpy(string,s.string,s.l+1);
        return *this;
    }
    return *this;
}

S    operator +(const S& first, const S& second)

{
    S temp;
    temp.string = strcat(first.strS(),second.strS());
    temp.l      = first.lenght() + second.lenght();

  return temp;
 }
```

I`m looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operator has bugs!

```
S temp;
//^^^^ has only one byte buffer!!!
temp.string = strcat(first.strS(),second.strS());
//   1 byte   ^^^^^ strcat appends second.strS to first.strS
```

You should re-allocate memory for temp:

```
S temp;
temp.l      = first.lenght() + second.lenght();
delete [] temp.string; // !!!! - 
temp.string = new char[temp.l + 1]; // !!!!
// you should have another c-tor which can allocate memory!!!
// like: S(unsigned length, unsigned char c = '\0') 
strcpy(temp.string, first.strS());
strcat(temp.string, second.strS());
```

Besides this obvious bug - you should also take care of exceptions - `std::bad_alloc` for example. Look at copy-and-swap idiom for better approach for this task.

Comment: Your solution will have undefined behavior if the `new char[temp.l + 1]` fails.  Messing around inside a string like this is a sure recipe for problems.  (In such cases, I'll occasionally define a private no-op constructor which can be used to create the temporary.  But it's rarely necessary.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Agree and that was why I added last sentence - an advise to use copy-and-swap idiom and to be care about exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

From [the manpage for strcat](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcat/):

> ```
>  The strcat() and strncat() functions append a copy of the null-terminated
>  string s2 to the end of the null-terminated string s1, then add a termi-
>  nating `\0'.  The string s1 must have sufficient space to hold the
>  result.
> ```

You're using it as if it allocates room for a new char array, then fills it.  But, it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `operator+` doesn't allocate any memory for the combined string. Nor does it copy the string to right place (it copies the string to first, not to temp). There's no easy fix with the class design you have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your implementation of `operator+`. `strcat()` appends the string ponted by the second argument to the string pointed by the first argument. The return value is the first argument. Therefore on return from `operator+` the resulting `S` and the first `S` argument will be pointing to the same buffer. Which will later be deleted twice...

Answer (score 0):

Check the description of `strcat`.  It appends the second argument to
the first, supposing both are null terminated strings, and returns the
first argument.  In your case:

- it appends to the `string` member of first, although there isn't
  enoguh memory for it (undefined behavior), and
- it sets the `string` pointer in `temp` to point to the same memory as
  that in `first`; the first one to be destructed leaves the other
  pointing to deleted memory, and the memory allocated in the default
  constructor of `temp` is leaked.

Also, you never terminate your strings with `'\0'`, so `strcat` may do
just about anything.

A better solution would be to implement `+=` first, and define `+` in
terms of it.  `+=` would have to grow the memory it has, and append the
text from the second string to it.

And while I'm at it: your `operator=` doesn't work either.  It will
leave the object in a state where it cannot be destructed if the `new`
fails (throwing `std::bad_alloc`).  You must ensure that all operations
that can fail occur *before* the `delete`.  (The fact that you need to
test for self assignment is a warning sign.  It's very rare for this
test to be necessary in a correctly written assignment operator.)  In
this case, the swap idiom would probably be your best bet: copy
construct a new `S` in a local variable, then swap their members.